# JAX-RS converting HashMap to XML or JSON

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I have a DB interface which returns me HashMap. I'm writing a JAX-RS REST interface to retrieve data from this DB and display in browser as either XML or JSON.

`@XmlRootELement` tag takes care of POJO to XML/JSON conversion.

How should I tackle Map to XML/JSON conversion?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Consider following Rest Interface. We define Annotation "Produces" which 
can generate different format type output. In your case APPLICATION_JSON will generate JSON 
and APPLICATION_XML will generate XML format. So decide accordingly.

```
package : javax.ws.rs.PathParam;

@GET
@Path("/helloRest")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public MyPojo getHello();
```

You can control how XML format is generated using Annotation from package 
javax.xml.bind.annotation. This will help you to control your POJO objects names and 
other validations if needed

```
@XmlRootElement(name="MyHello")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public  class MyPojo
{
    @XmlElement(name="id")
    private int id;
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 10, message = "Mandatory Field")
    @FormParam("code")
    private String code;
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50, message = "Mandatory Field")
    @FormParam("name")
    private String name;
    @FormParam("status")
    private String status;


JSON Format: 

{"id":48,"code":"dfgfdgd","name":"aaaaaaaaa","status":"dfgfdgdd"}


XML Format:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <MyHello><id>168</id>
    <code>AS3</code>
    <name>gfhfgh</name>
    <status>A</status>
</MyHello>
```